# REPMGR - change reconnect_attempts and reconnect_interval not working

Tags: postgresql, failover, postgresql-12, repmgr

I configured PostgreSQL automatic failover with REPMGR. But, in my simulation the sleeping time is 1 second for each reconnect attempt:
[image]

If I consult official documentation the default value to [reconnect interval is 10 seconds](http://#reconnect_interval=10%09%09%09#%20Interval%20between%20attempts%20to%20reconnect%20to%20an%20unreachable%20%09%09%09%09%09#%20primary%20(or%20other%20upstream%20node)).

> #reconnect_interval=10            # Interval between attempts to reconnect to an unreachable
> # primary (or other upstream node)

I tried to change values of reconnect attempts and interval in repmgr.conf and restart service of repmgr and use "repmgr standby register --force" but doesn't work.

My REPMGR.CONF

```
node_id = 2
node_name = 'PGCluster02'
data_directory='/var/lib/postgresql/12/main'
conninfo = 'host=PGCluster02 port=1010 user=my_repmgr dbname=dbrepmgr connection_timeout=2'
use_replication_slots=1
reconnect_attempts=30
reconnect_interval=10
failover=automatic
promote_command='/usr/bin/repmgr standby promote -f /etc/repmgr.conf --log-to-file'
follow_command='/usr/bin/repmgr standby follow -f /etc/repmgr.conf --log-to-file --upstream-node-id=%n'
```

Environment

```
PostgreSQL Version: 12.5
REPMGR Version: 5.2
Debian version: 10
```

Other tools in my environment are Barman (another VM) and PGBouncer (current VM)

How can I change the reconnect interval to 10 or 15 seconds? Anyone can help me?
I want to put my failover time to 5 minutes.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, it's already solved:

https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/repmgr/issues/673

> Issue has been reproduced and a fix applied, which will be in the upcoming 5.2.1 release.